# When debugging in Visualstudio Code, there is a transition to the crtexe.c file

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code

I ran into a problem while debugging a C program in visual studio code, namely when I get to the closing curly brace int main(int argc, char** argv) further pressing the F10 key does not end debugging as it used to, but opens an empty crtexe.c file in this path C: > M > mingw-w64-crt-git > src > mingw-w64 > mingw-w64-crt > crt > crtexe.c

This is my simple C code program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int first, second, temp;
  printf("Enter first number: ");
  scanf("%d", &first);
  printf("Enter second number: ");
  scanf("%d", &second);

  // value of first is assigned to temp
  temp = first;

  // value of second is assigned to first
  first = second;

  // value of temp (initial value of first) is assigned to second
  second = temp;

  // %.2lf displays number up to 2 decimal points
  printf("\nAfter swapping, first number = %d\n", first);
  printf("After swapping, second number = %d\n", second);
  return 0;
}
```

My launch.json file

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "C/C++: g++ build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
    },
    {
        "name": "(Windows) launch",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "console": "externalTerminal"
    }
]
```

}

How can I fix this so that after the last curly brace, my debugging automatically ends? P.S. of installed plugins I have: C/C++(Microsoft), C/C++ Extension Pack(Microsoft), C/C++ Themes, CMake, Cmake Tools, Code Runner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `main()` runs from a context, and this is the CRT, the C run time environment. This code (commonly) fulfills the promises the C standard gives you, like providing `argc` and `argv`, initializing all static objects, preparing `stdin` and `stdout`, and so on.

Now if `main()` returns, be it at the closing curly brace or via other means, it returns to the CRT. (Please note that there are other possibilities, but this is a different issue.)

<kbd>F10</kbd> is the shortcut for "step over", and you command the debugger to execute the next line of the current function. Since this is the last line of `main()`, it tries to show you the next statement after the call of `main()` in "crtexe.c". Since the source of library code is commonly *not available* in the sense of *not installed*, VSC shows you an empty view.

Because it is a legitimate request to step out of `main()`, this is the expected behavior.

If you want your debuggee to finish quietly, simply do not step out of `main()`. If you come to such a point, just press <kbd>F5</kbd> to continue the application, and all is well.

The same applies to any attempt to step into a function of a standard library. Save yourself from frustration and avoid it.

Comment: @SiarheiIonushas The recommended way to say "Thank you" is to mark the best answer after some time to let others add better answers, instead of a comment. ;-) You might want to take the [tour] to learn more, this is not a forum. Have a lot of fun!